# Using Google Cloud Function to load json files to Bigquery table, BQ job succeeded but some files missing in the BQ table

Tags: google-bigquery

Like I mentioned in the title, I created a google cloud function, when a json file is uploaded to the google cloud storage, the function is triggered and a load job is created to load the json file to a table in BigQuery as one row. No errors in the log, but I found some files couldn't be added in the table: I uploaded 10 json files, only 6 rows in the table. If 1.json is added to the table first, then 2.json couldn't, verse versa, and they have the same columns in the BQ table.
Here is the job config in the google cloud function:

```
uri = 'gs://%s/%s' % (bucketname, filename)
client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
job_config.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND',
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        table_id,
        job_config=job_config,
    )
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It is likely we are going to have to see more of the Cloud Function implementation.  Can you pare it down to a minimal example?

Comment: @Kolban, edited the question. The function is very simple, get the file uri, load into the bigquery table. The strange thing is both json files can be load into the table separately, but couldn't append to each other. Not sure if it's about the schema. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out some of the column types are not the same. Rookie mistake.